# mysql datetime shows differently on php page

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am working on shopping cart, which stores DateTime in orders table when order is placed.

one of the row in order table shows date time **2015-07-24 02:34:45**

When I display same on PHP page it displays **2015-07-24 01:43:33**

It is happening with all entries in orders table. I am considering just one here, date displays correctly but time is not displaying properly

Default time zone is **America/New_York**

I am just selecting rows from order table and displaying on a PHP page.

Comment: How are you displaying the date time on your page? How is the date stored on your database?

Comment: what framework / function are you using for displaying and saving date?

Comment: MySql and PHP have separate configurations for timezones.  So NOW() in MySql doesn't have to use the same timezone as set in PHP

Comment: Please specify the framework which you are using

Comment: Best to always save dates / times as UTC and adjust as needed when outputting. Makes life much easier and consistent.

Comment: @MarkBaker : just using echo $row['DateTime'];

Comment: Assuming that `$row['DateTime'];` is being read directly from the database, and not manipulated in any way in your PHP, then that's what has been read from the database as a string, so how are you reading this from the database? and is the database column a Date/Time datatype, or a varchar?

Comment: @MarkBaker : column name is DateTime, type datetime not varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting GLOBAL value by command line will be reset if you restart your MySql. Instead set this in your my.cnf like

```
default-time-zone = "America/New_York"
```

Don't forget to restart your MySql after setting the option

Answer (score 2):

**Mysql timezone != PHP timezone**, you need set both separately. If your php.ini have America/New_York you need execute this mysql query:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

Comment: it will be apply to current database or all database ?, i have number of other databse too